# Dao pattern Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to create a good pattern for my application. I want to reduce as much as possible the duplicate code and I want to use generics as much as possible. I have created a pattern for this but I want to know is there anything wrong with the code or  if is there any other better pattern already made for this.

BaseDao interface:

```
public interface BaseDao<T extends DTO> {

    List<T> fetchAll();

}
```

BaseImplementetion: all the DAO classes will extend this class.

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends DTO> implements BaseDao {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public BaseDaoImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;

    }

    @Override
    public List<T> fetchAll() {

    List<T> entities = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = doOpenSession();
        Query<T> query = session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName());
        entities = query.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return entities;
    }
```

UserDao interface:

```
public interface UserDao extends BaseDao{
    User getUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDao implementation:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao{

    public UserDaoImpl() {
    this(User.class);
    }
    private UserDaoImpl(Class<User> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(String name) {

    User user = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        String hql = "FROM User u WHERE u.username = :name";
        Query<User> query = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(1);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        user = query.uniqueResult();
    }
    return user;
    }
}
```

PS: So, I want to create all the basic operations (add, save, update, getAll etc) in my BaseDaoImpl and after that all the DAO classes to inherit the class.

Do you think this approach can bring me problems latter?

Comment: Just a little note: *"I want to use generics as much as possible"* should be rather "*I want to use generics as much as **reasonable***".

Comment: Another note: This question is rather for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or for [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah, as much as reasonable. I just want to avoid to write code in my all classes for update, delete, get etc.

Comment: Have you looked at GORM - from Grails? If I had the freedom to choose from a Java based platform I'd go for that instead. (Google Burt Beckwith - his blog - something like "An Army of Solopsists")

Comment: @JGFMK, people stopped using Groovy years ago. They are back to Java now. Though there are still some folks who are looking for miracles (Kotlin).

Comment: @John R. - bad motivation, bad approach, bad code. If you want to keep doing this - at least use bad frameworks (Spring Data). They already implemented such idea. But better - read a book on good old Domain Driven Design.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev any arguments for your answer? Without arguments your answer is not useful at all.

Comment: @JohnR., yeah first I tried to write a full answer with arguments and all, but that answer would've been either too long or too short. This topic is broad and opinionated. And I personally went through the same stage as you 10 years ago, so my emotions overwhelm me :) Anyway, I gave you 2 directions - either use the existing tool that already implements your ideas (it's very popular nowadays), or read the book. Or both.

Comment: I want to use just Java and Hibernate, without any other frameworks.

Comment: So, you say it is better to rewrite în every Dao class methods for get, save, update etc?